# List elements of a dataset's package

Tags: r, dataset

Say we have a dataset package like palmerpenguins, What R function can we use in order to show the names of the sub-datasets which are inside this package? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `datasets()` from package [`vcdExtra`](https://github.com/friendly/vcdExtra), which given a package name gives the name, dimension, and a bit of information about the datasets in that package.

```r
vcdExtra::datasets("palmerpenguins")

#> Loading package: palmerpenguins
#>                      Item      class    dim
#> 1                penguins data.frame  344x8
#> 2 penguins_raw (penguins) data.frame 344x17
#>                                                                                              Title
#> 1                    Size measurements for adult foraging penguins near Palmer Station, Antarctica
#> 2 Penguin size, clutch, and blood isotope data for foraging adults near Palmer Station, Antarctica
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

- We can use

```
data(package = "palmerpenguins")[["results"]][,"Item"]
```